# IN clause in pony orm query

Tags: python, ponyorm

How can I use subquery in pony orm for query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM  child_table
WHERE child_table.masterno IN (SELECT masterno
                    FROM   mastertable 
                    WHERE  mastertable.recorddate > SYSDATE -1)
```

In another word. I wanted to do somthing like

```
master_result = target_model.mastertable.select()\
                .filter(lambda mt: mt.recorddate > DATE)

output = target_model.child_table.select()\
           .filter(lambda ct: ct.masterno in master_result)
```

I got error

```
pony.orm.sqltranslation.IncomparableTypesError: Incomparable types 'int' and 'mastertable' in expression: ct.masterno in master_result
```

where master_result is

```
print(type(master_result))
```

<'pony.orm.core.QueryResult'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by Pony API you will get `QueryResult` object from `select()` and `filter()` functions. If you want to have entities from that query you could change your line 
`master_result = target_model.mastertable.select()\
                .filter(lambda mt: mt.recorddate > DATE)`
 to 
`master_result = target_model.mastertable.select()\
                .filter(lambda mt: mt.recorddate > DATE)[:] <- this will fetch objects`

Another way you can cast `QueryResult` to `list` like `results = list(master_result)`. Also you can iterate over QueryResult object and you will get Entity objects as item.

`for mastertable in mastertable.select():
    mastertable.recordtable = *smth*`